# swing apps with jdbc connectivity and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

```
stmt.executeUpdate("update fees set term_1 = "+hm.get("term_1").toString()+" term_2 ="+hm.get("term_1").toString()+"total = "+hm.get("total").toString()+"id = "+std_id);
```

Why it is not working when it is connected to `JDBC`?

Comment: Does the Swing tag and Swing in the title mean that that uncompilable code snippet works from a command line app.? If so, please show the Swing code, if not, don't mention Swing, as it has nothing to do with the problem!

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement is invalid, you are missing `comma(,)`

**Correct SQL Update statement should be**

```
update fees set term_1 = 'something', term_2='something', total='something' where id = something;
```

So your final Java statement will be like:

```
stmt.executeUpdate( " Update fees set term_1 = '"+hm.get("term_1").toString()+"',"
                  + " term_2 ='"+hm.get("term_1").toString()+"',"
                  + " total = "+hm.get("total").toString()+"'"
                  + " where id ="+std_id);
```

**Note :** Assuming all columns apart from id are of String type (i.e. term_1,term_2,total)